# Can I show svg in label swift?

Tags: swift, svg

I have found [this tutorial](https://medium.com/flawless-app-stories/display-image-containing-html-using-uilabel-and-detect-if-an-image-is-tapped-in-your-ios-apps-e042c6e614d1) for working with html where will be some images. Everything works well but this way can't show html with svg. As I see swift has some problems with svg processing :( I tried to insert image url directly to this code scope and display it:

```
let htmlString = "<html><body><img src=\"https://www.pngtosvg.com/images/mergeicon.svg\" width=\"360\" height=\"240\"></body></html>"
                            
cell.questionText.attributedText = htmlString.convertToAttributedFromHTML()
```

but as a result I saw only broken image symbol. Maybe someone knows how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The example is meant to be used with bitmapped images.
Here you can find more information on the use of svg's in Swift/Xcode:
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/72838

The simple explanation is that there is no support for svg in Swift/Objective-C. You can use pdf or bitmapped images. To use svg's you need extra frameworks/pods, and they will render the svg's to bitmapped image to use. However, in Xcode 12 and SwiftUI svg is supported, but that wasn't the question. youtu.be/A4ljGmzi3pQ

Comment: A good answer should also include the explanation here. Especially since Apple's forum links have a tendency to break.

Comment: This is a valid explanation, and you should edit your answer to include it.

Answer (score 1):

SVG's are supported only with Xcode 12 and iOS 13+. Keep in mind that the support applies to assets, it might just not work with NSAttributedString yet

Comment: So, as I understood I can't show svg image like in example?

Comment: If the code you pasted does not work with Xcode 12 than no. Try with a bitmap or a PDF if you want vector